# Как получить контент после успешной авторизации с помощью cURL?

Tags: php, curl

Я не понимаю как получить контент или редирект на нужную страницу (авторизованную) после успешной авторизации, разве curl выдал пустой контент с статусом 200 ок?

Вот заголовки ответа после авторизации $url:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Date: Wed, 23 Jan 2019 12:05:21 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=cp1251 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive Vary: Accept-Encoding Set-Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=o92jr85c6vl8c6ict8jaff5p92; path=/ Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981
>   08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate,
>   post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Vary: Accept-Encoding

А вот и контент с $url2 выдает контент только с авторизацией а не авторизованный контент.

Как получить авторизованный контент или редирект на нужную страницу (авторизованную)? Спасибо заранее. Внизу прилагаю мой код PHP.

```
function curlfile($url, $url2){

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username=логинpassword=пассlogin=submit');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   #if(preg_match('#Location: ([\S]+)#',$data,$rr)){$preg = $rr[1];} else {die('error c1');}
   curl_close($ch);
   return $data;
}

var_dump(curlfile('сайт.логин.php', 'сайт/index.php'));
```

Comment: вы осуществляете как вы думаете 2 запроса - судя по коду. Вы вообще понимаете как работает CURL и HTTP протокол ? И каким образом авторизация в общем случае осуществляется?

Comment: В вашем коде можете удалить строку curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); потому что вы ее затираете вот тут curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2); В итоге ваша функция делает 1 запрос на адрес $url2. Вообще постарайтесь писать по-русски, а то слова понятны а смысл вопроса..ну так :(